# ASP.NET MVC Best Practice: Passing data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, model-view-controller

This might be an obvious question, but let's say I wanted to pass some data into my view and immediately want to handle it with javascript. It seems like a true MVC architecture would require this data to be passed using a ViewModel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeViewModel model = PopulateSomeViewModel();
    return View( model );
}
```

and then accessed in the view using Razor syntax `@Model.SomeData`

However, I also understand that I *can* (should? should not?) use jQuery's HTTP `get` method to call the `PopulateSomeViewModel()` method from the view:

```
$().get("/SomeController/PopulateSomeViewModel")
```

and then handle the data as I need.

In ASP.NET MVC and and MVC design in general, would the second approach be fine or is it technically wrong?

Comment: Normally a method like `PopulateSomeViewModel()` will be a private method and not a controller endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ASP.NET MVC and and MVC design in general, would the second
>   approach be fine or is it technically wrong?

Each has its own usage so there is no right or wrong.

### 1st Approach

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeViewModel model = PopulateSomeViewModel();
    return View( model );
}
```

Access the model as `@Model.SomeData` inside View. It is a strongly-typed, and the common approach in MVC if you want to access the model inside View in the ***same HTTP request***.

### 2nd Approach

```
$.ajax({
   url: API_URL,
   contentType: "application/json",
   method: "GET",
   data: JSON.stringify({"id": 1}, 
   success: function(result) { return result; }
});
```

We use Ajax *only if* we need to access server-side data from client-side after the page is fully loaded. Note that it is a round trip to the server, and not a replacement for the 1st approach.